# Elasticsearch regexp filter syntax with lowercase_expanded_terms

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

**Problem:**

**I want to execute a query that matches text, then performs a regex filter on some field. 
For the life of me, I cant figure out the correct syntax for a regex filter.**

(I am using using the node.js client to execute queries)

---

Explanation:

The `land` field in my documents is set to `index:'not_analyzed'`. I have verified the query works without the filter clause. I have verified that there are items in the land field with patterns such as `'T2-R3'`. I understand from reading the documentation that it is necessary to include `lowercase_expanded_terms: false` parameter to the query because the default behavior of regex expansion is only lower case.

What's wrong with my query:

```
es.search({
    index: index_list,
    type: 'page',
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    {match: { _all: {
                            "query": search_text,
                            "operator": "and"
                            }}},
                ],
                filter: [ 
                    {"regexp": {land: 'T*',
                        lowercase_expanded_terms: false}}
                ]
            }
        },
        aggs: {
            "top_tag_hits":{
                terms: {
                    field: "agg_index",
                    size: agg_size
                },
                aggs: {
                    "hits":{
                        top_hits: {
                            size: agg_size
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    explain: true,
    size: result_size, 
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits;
    var aggs = resp.aggregations;
    response.send(aggs);
}, function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
    response.send(err.message);
});
```

I expect this is probably a stupid syntax error. But there are precious few elasticsearch examples around, and none that I've found that use both a regex filter and set `lowercase_expanded_terms`

Elasticsearch version 2.3

Answer (score 1):

The regex in your query, `T*`, will not match the value in your example, `T2-R3`

`*` is the operator for "Match the preceding token 0 or more times", so it will only match documents where the `land` field contains only T's

Hopefully that's the only problem

Comment: Definitely should have read `T.*` in the original question. Turns out my issue is more complicated however. Will update question